# Help with ASP.NET 4.0 routing and subfolders

Tags: asp.net, routes

If I use routing with 2 query parameters, like this:

```
System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("HomeRoute", "home/{f1}/{f2}", "~/Home.aspx");
```

My image does not appear on my Home.aspx page:

```
<img src="~/img/img.jpg" /> or <img src="img/img.jpg" />
```

But it does appear when I access the `http://localhost:3760/Website/Home.aspx` URL

I tried using Routing.Ignore with no luck. I look for a solution wich should work for an unlimited number of subfolders: "home/{f1}/{f2}/.../{fn}"

The problem is raised by ASP.NET routing module. The image will show if I type `<img src="../../img.jpg" />` but this goes further to `<img src="../../../img.jpg" />` if I have "home/{f1}/{f2}/{f3}" on the routing rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i can see that `<img src="~/img/img.jpg" />` is wrong
it should be `<img src="<%=Page.ResolveClientUrl(~/img/img.jpg)%>" />`

This is because ~ is an asp symbol, not a html symbol.

Unfortunately i do not know if this is your actual problem

Comment: yes, you are right, thank you. Isn't there another simpler solution ? I don't want to type ResolveClientUrl on every image that I use

Comment: you can look at what  Page.ResolveClientUrl resolves to in your html page and use that url.  Personally i prefer the asp bit.  If your site structure changes this can save a lot of time